# Extract data from file with python and write new file

Tags: python, readfile, text-parsing

I'm trying to extract data from a file with this structure

> ```
>         //Side Menu
>         market: 'Market',
>         store: 'Store',
>         stores: 'Stores',
>         myNotes: 'My Notes',
>         logout: 'Logout',
>         //Toast
>         activeUserHasChanged: 'Resetting app - the active user has changed.',
>         loginHasExpired: 'Your login has expired.',
>         appIsReseting: 'The app is resetting.',
> ```

what I want is to extract the all the text that is between single quotation marks and put it in a new file, I think Python could be a good option but I new to programming and Python, I tried something but no luck and for what I've read it shouldn't be a small script.

My expected output is:

> ```
>          Market,
>          Store,
>          Stores,
>          My Notes,
>          Logout,
>          Resetting app - the active user has changed,
>          Your login has expired,
>          The app is resetting,
> ```

So any help on this will be appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Post what your expected output (new file) would look like.

Comment: Done, I edit the question and put my expected output.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is something like:

```
in_string = False
with open('infile.txt','r') as fr, open('outfile.txt','w') as fw:
  for char in fr.read():
    if char == "'":
      in_string = in_string != True  # XOR
    elif in_string:
      fw.write(char)
```

The intuition is that we read the file character-by-character and keep track of any `'` we see along the way. When we encounter the first, we write the next characters to the output file until we encounter the second, etc.

It does not handle invalid input, and doesn't do buffering or anything fancy. But if you just have small files, which are well-formed this is should do it.
It also doesn't format your output in lines with commas, but that shouldn't be too hard to do from here.

Comment: Thanks for your time, this works.  One more question, how can I add a breakline to this script?

Comment: In the `if char == "'":` you can check if you are already inside the string. If so, write a comma and a line break to the output file as well.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have input as a text file

```
import re
fid = open('your input file','rb')
output = open('output file','wb')
for i in fid:
    m = re.match(r"['\"](.*?)['\"]",i)
    if m is not None:
        output.write(m.group(1)+'\r\n')
fid.close()
output.close()
```

r"'\"['\"]" this regex will let you find anything between single quotation. If nothing found, then skip. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Hi SuWon, thanks for your time, one question..

Im running the script as Python extract.py (extract is the name of my file) and Im getting the following error:

raceback (most recent call last):
  File "extract.py", line 6, in <module>
    if m.group(1) is not None:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Don't know if Im missing something.

Comment: @kennechu Sorry. I just made a correction. Please try again.